# How to format a list in Python as a table

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, formatting, format

I have two separate lists that I want to format as a table.

```
keys = ('banana', 'broccoli', 'beans', 'apple')
values = (5, 1, 1, 1)
```

In the list above, it counts how many fruits there are available. For instance, there are 5 bananas and 1 broccoli. Note that the names of the fruit have different lengths. Preferably, I would like to not have to import any modules. Is there a way that I can format these lists so that it looks like:

```
'Banana'   | 5
'Broccoli' | 1
'Beans'    | 1
'Apple'    | 1
```

I have already tried using this code:

```
row_format ="{:>15}" * (len(items) + 1)
print(row_format.format("", *items))
for keys, values in zip(items, keys):
    print(row_format.format(values, *row))
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: What's the output of that code?

Comment: It just gives me a NameError that the name "items" is not defined, but I have already defined it beforehand.

Comment: are you suggesting that python is *lying* about the `NameError`?

Comment: The list is named `keys` (or `values`) not `items`.

Comment: When I change "items" to "keys" it says that the name 'keys' is not defined.

Comment: @Chris_Rands Never mind, you were right. I forgot to indent the code.

Comment: Also these are tuples, not lists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
keys = ('banana', 'broccoli', 'beans', 'apple')
values = (5, 1, 1, 1)

max_length = len(max(keys, key=len))

for k, v in zip(keys, values):
    print("{: <{width}} | {}".format(repr(k).title(), v, width=max_length + 2))
```

Prints:

```
'Banana'   | 5
'Broccoli' | 1
'Beans'    | 1
'Apple'    | 1
```

Answer (score 0):

you ca use:

```
width = max(len(w) for w in keys) 
print(''.join(f'{k:{width}} | {v}\n' for k, v in zip(keys, values)))

# output: 
# banana   | 5
# broccoli | 1
# beans    | 1
# apple    | 1
```